# Can't override ValidatorUpdateIsValid asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'trying to use this method to validate my form

http://blog.alanta.nl/2008/09/extending-aspnet-validation-on-client.html#Blog1_cmt-508747036038885038

My website was asp.NET 4.6 webform.

I'm using master page where there are all script reference.
In my page I've inserted

```
<div class="form-group">                                                        
   <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNomeOperatore" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>                            
   <span class="help-block">Operatore</span>
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="NomeOperatoreValidator" Text="Errore richiamato" ControlToValidate="txtNomeOperatore" Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="true" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</div>
```

at the end of page I've inserted Javascript code:

```
<script>
        ValidatorUpdateIsValid = function () {
            Page_IsValid = AllValidatorsValid(Page_Validators);
            SetValidatorStyles();
        }

        SetValidatorStyles = function () {
            var i;
            // clear all
            for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
                var inputControl = document.getElementById(Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate);
                if (null != inputControl) {
                    WebForm_RemoveClassName(inputControl, 'validate-error');
                }
            }
            // set invalid
            for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
                inputControl = document.getElementById(Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate);
                if (null != inputControl && !Page_Validators[i].isvalid) {
                    WebForm_AppendToClassName(inputControl, 'validate-error');
                }
            }

        }
</script>
```

but when try to validate style was not applied to my control
Where I wrong?

Comment: I've tested the snippet. It works and the class is added/removed. There must be something else that is causing the problem.

Comment: Sure..but what?